# Users encountering "List does not exist. The page you might selected contains a list that does not exist........"

Tags: 2007

One of your customer's SharePoint 2007 portal is behaving in an usual way. When site collection administrators logs in we are able to successfully log in and access the home page but when any non-site collection administrator logs in he/she ends up with the below given error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an immediate troubleshooting points you can verify permissions of the effected user/group against the following:-

1. Homepage permissions - a) Validate if there are any unique permissions set for the homepage. 
   b) Validate the homepage is not in a checked out or pending approval state.
2. Library permissions - Validate the permissions of the document library where the homepage is residing.
3. Any webpart/list view added in the homepage - Validate if there are any list added as webpart on the home page. If yes, validate the list permission.
4. Masterpage - Check for the status of the applied masterpage and
   ensure that it is not in a checkedout or pending approval state.

Additionally, there are times when you have [Alternate Access Mappings configuration](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/sharepoint2010general/thread/e9329af7-5d97-4d5c-aa3c-61a313b3d988) related problems due to which this error comes.  Then there are has been scenarios where deactivating and activating the publishing feature fixed the issue. It is advised that you share the ULS logs, incase the above troubleshooting tips does not help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, there is a web part on that page that references a list or library with custom permissions, and those users do not have permissions to see that list/library.

Have one of those users navigate to All Site Content(_layouts/viewlsts.aspx). Can they see the lists referenced in the home page?

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for the reply. I have checked what you have mentioned and everything looks perfect. The users are able to navigate to All Site Content(_layouts/viewlsts.aspx) and have also confirmed nothing is deleted from anywhere.

Comment: Then try this: Delete all the web parts from the page(make a copy first using SPD so you can restore it if you need to).  Can the users see the page now?  if so add the web parts back in one by one until you find the one that is breaking things.